# Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

How can I put in variable response from service and then display it on hover?
I tried this:

```js
toolTip: string;

async mouseover(params) {
    this.handle = setTimeout(() => {
        this.toolTip = this.checkSaldo(10, 'FRA');
        this.show = true;
    }, 4000);

}

checkSaldo(amount: any, currencyCode: any): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.restService.getByParam('recalculatedSaldo', { amount: amount, currency: currencyCode }).subscribe(response => {
            resolve(response.payload);
        });
    })

}
```

but I'm getting an error on `toolTip` variable:

> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'string'

Any suggestion?

Comment: I might be mistaken here but you are subscribing to a service. That means you are using an observable. Why wrapping it in a promise ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't assign the `Promise` into a `string` field.

But, you need to wait the Promise callback and assign the value as below:

```js
this.checkSaldo(10, 'FRA').then((x) => {
    this.toolTip = x;
    ...
});
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rrakff?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: when i use this:

 async checkSaldo(amount: any, currencyCode: any): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.restService.getByParam('recalculatedSaldo', { amount: amount, currency: currencyCode }).subscribe(response => {
                resolve(response);
            });
        });

    }

im getting an error:

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.

any suggestion how can i fix this?

Comment: Hi, for your previous code did `request.payload` return string? If yes, you should remain `resolve(response.payload)`. The demo I created is just a mock on how you get the value from promise.

Comment: yes, in response.payload it return string

Comment: even if i put fixed some string in resolve(response) for example resolve('test') i get same error

Comment: Can you try reproduce the error in StackBlitz?

Comment: to be honest i dont know why because first method im using its same as you...just this checkSaldo making me a problem maybe because im using "custom" service his.restService.getByParam

Comment: i fixed adding Promise<any> and not a string.